# PuLP LpVariable of binary type giving value 2

Tags: python, pulp

So I wrote few conditions

```
keys=['a','b','c']
var=LpVariable.dicts('var',(keys,[1,2,3]),cat='Binary')

for key in keys:
   prob+=lpSum([var[key][j] for j in [1,2,3]])==2
```

Even though I am getting optimal result, for some keys I see that var is taking value 2.0. Why this is happening and is there any solution to it?

Comment: is the  LpStatus[prob.status] returning optimal ? i would assume this wouldn't be case since the variable is out of bounds

Comment: Yes it is returning optimal. I also tried assigning the bounds but again it's crossing the bounds

Comment: Can you share a completeminimal example that reproduces the problem?